# Problem with convergence in measure of $f_n={1\over n}\mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I proved that $f_n={1\over n}\mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}$ converges to $0$ uniformly and I know uniform convergence implies convergence in measure, but I tried to do it using the definition of convergence in measure.
I'm using this definition:
The sequence $(f_n)$ converges in measure to $f$ in case
$\mu($$\lbrace$x/ $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert\ge\epsilon\rbrace) \rightarrow 0$  $\quad$ as $n\rightarrow +\infty$
for each $\epsilon>0$

In the problem, I got this:
Let $E=${$x$/ $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert\ge\epsilon$}

$E=${$x$/ $\lvert f_n(x)-0\rvert\ge\epsilon$}$ \quad\forall \epsilon>0$
$E=${$x$/ $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert>0$}
$E=${$x$/ ${1\over n}\mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}>0$}
$E=${$x$/ $\mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}>0$}
Since $\mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}$ only takes values $0$ or $1$, then it takes $1$, and this implies $x\in[0,n]$.
Then, $E=${$x/x\in[0,n] $}
$E=[0,n]$
$\mu(E)=n \rightarrow +\infty$
So the sequence does not converge in measure to $0$.
This is wrong, but why?

Comment: You need to *fix* an $\epsilon>0$ and then show $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(E)=0$, where $E$ is as you first defined it.

Comment: @KaboMurphy There is a mistake in his proof. You need to fix an $\epsilon$ and then prove that $\mu (\{ x \mid \frac{1}{n} \mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}(x) \geq \epsilon \}) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$. The set is eventually empty for every $\epsilon$, so the measure clearly converges to $0$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy $I_{(0,n)}$ is not a counterexample because it doesn't converge uniformly. In fact there is no counterexample because even almost uniform convergence implies convergence in measure for infinite measures as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sequence does  converge in measure to $0$  because $\frac  1 n <\epsilon$ eventually. Uniform convergence always implies convergence in measure for a similar reason.

Many thanks to David Mitra for correcting my mistakes.

Comment: Uniform convergence implies convergence in measure even for non finite measures. See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29605/601235